# Is it possible to manipule the incoming mule request at policy level?

Tags: mule

How to change the `http.request.path` from incoming mule message at policy level?

My frontend application is configured with a wrong call /abc instead of /abc/xyz. So the call is able to come to the router proxy but there is no sub proxy in our domain which listens for the /abc and the call is failing.

We have custom policy at router proxy for some validation. So do we have any trick or logic by which we can change the request path to the correct one as we do not want to do the changes at proxy level?

Answer (score 0):

This is more some kind of ugly workaround than a real solution, but you can add a flow with some HTTP Listener configured to listen on `/abc` and make a call to `/abc/xyz` before returning, something like:

```
    <flow name="test-bulkFlow1">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/abc" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="abc/xyz/" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    </flow>
```

Though the best thing to do is simply to correct this bug in your front app.